# What is up with Tsukihi and Karen's boyfriends' names?

Tags: monogatari-series

In Tsubasa Family and Tsubasa Tiger, it was mentioned in a conversation between the Fire Sisters and Tsubasa that both Karen and Tsukihi have boyfriends<sup>[1][2]</sup>.

Karen's boyfriend is named Mizudori （瑞鳥【みずどり】）.

Tsukihi's boyfriend is named Rousokuzawa （蠟燭澤【ろうそくざわ】）.

What is up with these ridiculous names? Has the author explained the names or expanded the story on who they are?

<sup><sup>1</sup> Light novel - Nekomonogatari (White) Chapter 059. Anime - Monogatari Series: Second Season Episode 4.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Light novel - Nekomonogatari (Black) Chapter 002. Anime - Nekomonogatari: Black Episode 1 (only Tsukihi's boyfriend's name is mentioned).</sup>

Comment: What's romaji for the second name? Rousokuzawa?

Comment: @user1306322: Ah, yes. I forgot to include the Romaji.

Comment: I read a doujinshi that had an elaborate theory based on the kanji and connotations of those two names, saying that the names refer to Karen and Tsukihi themselves. That is, the doujinshi was saying that they're each other's boyfriends, and they made up the names to hide it from their family. In general, Nisio Isin comes up with some pretty ridiculous names; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaregoto_Series#Characters and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Medaka_Box_characters.

Comment: I think other family names in monogatari series

Comment: are also strange.[This page](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1284696547) say only one family use Araragi and no family use the name Senjougahara, Oshino or Hachikuji.

Comment: Should the comments of Torisuda and kumagaro not be included as answers?

Comment: The author likes to do word play on the character names. It might just be a Nisio Isin quirk.

Answer (score 13):

## From official source

I tried to find some comments from the author on the Japanese internet, but came up empty-handed due to my lack of knowledge of Japanese. I do have some very tenuous evidence that as of 2013, there was no such explanation even in Japanese, discussed below.

According to the [Japanese Wikipedia page on the Monogatari series](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%80%88%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E%E3%80%89%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA#.E4.B8.BB.E8.A6.81.E4.BA.BA.E7.89.A9), very little is known about Mizudori-kun and Rousokuzawa-kun except that Mizudori-kun is shorter than Karen-chan and Rousokuzawa-kun is taller than Tsukihi-chan, suggesting that they look similar to Koyomi and adding evidence for the Fire Sisters' massive brother complex. Tsukihi-chan talks a little about Rousokuzawa-kun in Neko Black, during which she says he wants to fondle breasts in a set-theoretic sense, and also says during Tsukihi Phoenix that her relationship with him is chaste; she also says that Karen-chan and Mizudori-kun haven't been getting along. The [Monogatari series wikia](http://bakemonogatari.wikia.com/) also has next to nothing to say about them. Since Koyomi, the viewpoint character, has absolutely refused to meet them, we've so far never seen them, and it seems that they're more a minor plot detail than anything; as far as I can tell, what I listed above is the sum total of our knowledge about them.

As for their names, Nisio Isin, author of the Monogatari series, has a history of making up bizarre names for his characters, usually ones full of pun and subtext, and it seems the more minor they are, the more bizarre the names get. From the Monogatari series itself, I submit "Kaiki Deishuu" and "Kiss-shot Acerola Orion Heart-Under-Blade" and the name "Valhalla Combi" for the combination of Senjougahara and Kanbaru; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaregoto_Series#Characters and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Medaka_Box_characters for examples from his other work.

## Fan's interpretation

The next part is a little tangential since it involves an unofficial doujinshi, but I take it as evidence that Japanese audiences also had no access to an explanation as of April 2013 (the doujinshi's publication date) since they were making up their own theories. I once found a doujinshi (a very, very NSFW doujinshi, which could get you fired if you happen to be at work, so I'm not going to provide a link, but the title is *Sukimonogatari* - [SFW Cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlYpf.jpg)) that offered a theory on the names "Rousokuzawa-kun" and "Mizudori-kun", along with a random sex scene. Here's part of a page (edited to be SFW) that explains some of the theory:

[image: Page 12 from Sukimonogatari]

Note that in the doujinshi, boys named "Mizudori-kun" and "Rousokuzawa-kun" don't exist; "Mizudori-kun" is Tsukihi-chan, and "Rousokuzawa-kun" is Karen-chan. The upper-left panel gives a chain of transformations:

[月火]【Tsukihi】 (Moon | Fire)
→ [水]【Mizu】 (Water. Based on day of the week progression from Sunday to Saturday: 日月火水木金土)
→ [瑞]【Mizu】 (Good omen. A kanji with the same reading as "water")
→ [瑞鳥]【Mizudori】 (Auspicious bird).

[火憐]【Karen】 (Fire | Pity)
→ [燐]【Rin】 (Phosphorus. Take the second character and replace the heart radical 忄 with fire radical 火)
→ [燐寸]【Macchi】 (Match. Match head contains phosphorus)
→ [蠟燭澤]【Rousokuzawa】 (蠟燭 means candle. 澤 or equivalent [shinjitai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjitai) 沢 is a common character used in names)

Koyomi takes note of the terrifying coincidence in the names they give each other and the kaii that they are affected. Tsukihi-chan, called "Mizudori", is a bird kaii, and "auspicious bird" can refer to phoenix. Karen-chan, called "Rousokuzawa", was afflicted by a bee kaii, and candles can be made of beeswax. When Koyomi asked why they choose such names, the Fire Sisters explain that they chose those names because migrating **birds** and [**candle** clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candle_clock) are both methods of telling time, which aligns with the fact that the entire Araragi family has names with timekeeping and calendar themes<sup>1</sup>.

## Conclusion

In summary, nothing much is said about these two in the novels or anime up through the end of the second season, and no explanation is given for their names up to that point. Although I didn't find anything official, the very scant information on these two, along with the (admittedly weak) evidence of the doujinshi, suggests that they're another example of Nisio Isin's famously bizarre punny names for his characters, and no, he isn't going to explain them (that would ruin the fun).

## Footnote

1. [暦]【Koyomi】 means calendar.

   [火憐]【Karen】 contains the prefix of カレンダー, i.e. calendar.

   Tsukihi　（月火） can be rendered as 月日, which contains the kanji for moon and sun, which also means month and day.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks for the edits, it looks good. I'm sure this wasn't the kind of answer you were hoping for; maybe someone else can find an official statement or more definitive evidence that there isn't one.

Comment: I actually like the Fan Theory, kinda cute how to hide their incest relationship by giving each other a male-ish name and pretend to be each other's "boyfriend"

Comment: @Memor-X Me too. As a huge Fire Sisters fan (look who's on my profile pic), I went ahead and included it in my post even though the evidence it gives for an answer to nhahtdh's question holds up about as well as Koyomi's body does in every fight in the series.

Comment: @Torisuda: This answer is somewhat within my expectation, since I also read the same doujinshi before posting this question, and I think the theory is quite good, but you are right that I am looking for an official statement about this.

Comment: "a very, very NSFW doujinshi, which could get you fired if you happen to be at work" I didn't read this before I google :(

Comment: @ShinobuOshino Sorry about that. I hope I didn't get you fired.